# Is there a prime between the double of two consecutive primes

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Can we say that there always exists a prime in between $2p_i$ and $2p_{i+1}$ $\forall i \in {N}$

It seems likely, and I thought that we could consider the inverse that, for a prime $p_i, \frac{p_i}{2}$ is in between two consecutive primes

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me! But I can't find a counter-example in my head. As for your second conjecture: _every_ non-prime number is in between two consecutive primes, even numbers that are not integers (like for instance $p_i/2$).

Comment: First counter-example: $p_i=59, p_{i+1}=61$.

Comment: @TonyK Nice! I suppose it's worthwhile asking if there is an absolute constant $C$ such that there is a prime between $Cp_{i}, Cp_{i+1}$ for every index $i$.

Comment: Also does not work for consecutive primes 107 and 109.

Comment: twin primes, only have 1 number between  them doubled that could be prime.

Comment: Following on Roddy MacPhee (and other twin prime examples in comments), $101$ and $103$ are prime, but $203,204,205$ are all composite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not even exist any constant $C>0$ such that there is always a prime between $Cp_j$ and $Cp_{j+1}$. By the work of Zhang–Maynard–Tao, there exists a constant $D$ such that the number of prime pairs $p,p+D$ up to $x$ is $\gg x/\log^2 x$. On the other hand, an upper bound sieve shows that for each $0<A<CD$, the number of primes $p\le x$ for which $p, Cp+A, p+D$ are all prime is $\ll x/\log^3 x$. Therefore for most prime pairs $p,p+D$, there will be no prime between $Cp$ and $C(p+D)$.